Laravel Horizon - What is actually running
Within horizon, jobs with Pending status can be:Delayed for later, waiting on a slot/capacity to run, running, or orphaned (horizon went away).
We need to be able to determine on a given supervisor node which processes are actually running. Is there a way to do this through looking at process lists, Redis queue information, or artisan commands?

Have you found any solution for this?
